# Is CursorAdapter more efficient that ListAdapter/ArrayAdapter?

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin.android, android-cursor

I'm using Mono For Android to create my Android app.

My solution is structured as such:

- Core -> A .Net Class Library that contains my business logic. Doesn't have Android code. Needs to be interoperable.
- Core.AndroidLib -> An Android Class Library. Contains Android specific code
- MyApp -> The Android Application Project. Contains the layouts, activities, etc.

The Core contains my entities (i.e. `Student`). My `Student` class has a property `IEnumerable<Schedule> Schedules`. This property is populated from a web service (`GetAllSchedules()`). To conserve resource, data downloaded from the service it is cached to a local SQLite database (the caching logic resides in Core.AndroidLib). Whenever Schedule data is requested, it first checks the Cache and only go to the web service if additional data is needed.

Up to this point, Core remains a pure .Net Class library.

After reading about Cursors, I realized that Cursor is somehow more efficient in querying because data are "fetched" only when it is needed (as opposed to pre-populating my `IEnumerable<Schedule> Schedules` all at once and storing it in a list).

Instead of storing Schedule data in a List, I'm thinking about storing it in a Cursor (i.e. `ICursor Schedule`), however, this approach will make my Core library not interoperable as it will use classes from the Android library.

Should I just keep Schedule data in the list and just pre-populate data from the SQL (`Select * from Schedules`) or should I expose an ICursor? Will exposing ICursor be more efficient that fetching all data and storing it in a list?

Comment: the efficiency is in the memory when the screen is open. CursorAdapter doesn't load everything into the RAM